# TFS how to unmerge a merge?

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015, merge

I was working on a local copy of project in VS2015. When I tried to check in the changes, it prompted me with conflicts with server copy and asked me to merge the changes. I went through the conflicts and did a merge i.e. what i wanted to do was merge the changes i made on my local copy with the server version. Instead it's gone and updated all the work I did on my local copy with what was previously on the server version - totally not what I wanted.

I haven't yet checked in this merge. How can I get back my local copy prior to the merge and then push these changes back on to the server version.

I'm new to TFS so some step by step instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In the future, you can create shelvesets to save a copy of work-in-progress to the server without actually committing it prior to potentially risky operations.